# fill multiple dropdown using jquery populate form

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

```
 ![$.getJSON('admin/admin/update-data/action_page/MasterTransportBusRoutes/data_id/' + dataId, function(data) {
                formPopulate("frm_add_update", data)
                //json_str = JSON.stringify(data);populateForm("frm_add_update", json_str)

                $.each(data.ddl_msbr_id, function (index, value) {
                alert(value.route_suburb_ids);
        });
            })][2]
```

I am using this code to fill the form using jquery formPopulate.its working fine apart from the multiple select dropdown.Can you please help me out how to show multiple option selected when some edit.

```
JSON data:{"hid_id":"5","ddl_mtb_id":"3","txt_route_name":"Pramod Master Test","ddl_msbr_id":[{"route_suburb_ids":"1"},{"route_suburb_ids":"3"}]}
```